# Data Normalization

Tags: list-manipulation

I am having trouble selecting certain region from the data. I have data such that,

[image]

where A and B are the transparent region.

I want to normalize data by setting these transparent regions to 1, so I want to first fit the linear function f[x] by using data from region A and B such that

[image]

If I can find the function, then it is easy to normalize the data,

```
Table[data2[[i]]/f[i],{i,1,Length[data2]}].
```

However, it is hard to select the date in arbitrary transparent region. Any one can give me any idea to find this region?

Thank you!

```
data2={0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, \
0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, \
0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.648, 0.656, 0.656, 0.648, 0.656, 0.656, \
0.656, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, \
0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.648, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.648, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, \
0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, \
0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.632, 0.632, 0.64, 0.632, \
0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, \
0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, \
0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.648, \
0.64, 0.648, 0.64, 0.648, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, \
0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, \
0.648, 0.656, 0.648, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, \
0.656, 0.656, 0.664, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.664, 0.656, \
0.664, 0.664, 0.656, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, \
0.664, 0.664, 0.672, 0.672, 0.664, 0.664, 0.672, 0.664, 0.672, 0.672, \
0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, \
0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, \
0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, \
0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, \
0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.664, 0.664, 0.672, \
0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, \
0.656, 0.664, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.648, \
0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.64, 0.648, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, \
0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.632, 0.632, 0.632, 0.632, 0.632, 0.632, 0.632, \
0.624, 0.624, 0.616, 0.616, 0.616, 0.616, 0.616, 0.616, 0.616, 0.616, \
0.608, 0.608, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.592, 0.592, 0.592, \
0.584, 0.584, 0.584, 0.584, 0.584, 0.576, 0.576, 0.576, 0.576, 0.568, \
0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552, \
0.544, 0.544, 0.544, 0.544, 0.544, 0.544, 0.536, 0.536, 0.536, 0.528, \
0.528, 0.528, 0.528, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.512, \
0.512, 0.512, 0.504, 0.504, 0.512, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, \
0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.496, 0.496, 0.496, 0.496, 0.488, 0.488, \
0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.48, 0.488, 0.48, 0.48, \
0.48, 0.48, 0.488, 0.48, 0.488, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, \
0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.488, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, \
0.488, 0.48, 0.48, 0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.488, \
0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.488, 0.496, 0.496, \
0.496, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.512, \
0.512, 0.512, 0.512, 0.512, 0.52, 0.512, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.528, \
0.528, 0.536, 0.536, 0.536, 0.536, 0.536, 0.536, 0.544, 0.544, 0.544, \
0.544, 0.544, 0.552, 0.552, 0.552, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56, 0.568, \
0.568, 0.568, 0.576, 0.576, 0.576, 0.584, 0.584, 0.584, 0.584, 0.592, \
0.592, 0.592, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.608, 0.608, 0.608, 0.616, 0.616, \
0.616, 0.616, 0.616, 0.624, 0.624, 0.624, 0.632, 0.632, 0.632, 0.64, \
0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.648, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.664, \
0.664, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.688, \
0.688, 0.688, 0.688, 0.696, 0.696, 0.696, 0.696, 0.704, 0.704, 0.704, \
0.704, 0.712, 0.712, 0.712, 0.712, 0.72, 0.72, 0.728, 0.728, 0.728, \
0.728, 0.728, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.744, 0.736, 0.744, \
0.744, 0.752, 0.744, 0.744, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.76, \
0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.768, 0.768, \
0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.776, 0.768, 0.768, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.784, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.776, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, \
0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.776, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, \
0.784, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.784, 0.792, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, \
0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.792, 0.784, 0.792, 0.784, 0.784, 0.792, 0.784, \
0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.792, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, \
0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, \
0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.776, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, \
0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.776, 0.784, 0.776, \
0.784, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.784, 0.776, 0.784, 0.784, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.784, 0.776, 0.784, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.784, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.784, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.784, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.768, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.768, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.784, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.768, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.784, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.784, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.768, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.768, 0.768, 0.776, 0.776, 0.768, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.768, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.768, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.768, \
0.768, 0.768, 0.776, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, \
0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, \
0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.76, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, \
0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.768, \
0.76, 0.768, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, \
0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.752, 0.76, 0.76, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, \
0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, \
0.752, 0.752, 0.744, 0.744, 0.744, 0.744, 0.744, 0.744, 0.744, 0.744, \
0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, \
0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.728, 0.728, 0.728, 0.728, 0.72, 0.728, \
0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.712, 0.72, 0.712, \
0.712, 0.712, 0.712, 0.712, 0.712, 0.712, 0.704, 0.712, 0.704, 0.712, \
0.704, 0.704, 0.696, 0.704, 0.704, 0.696, 0.696, 0.704, 0.696, 0.696, \
0.696, 0.696, 0.696, 0.696, 0.696, 0.688, 0.696, 0.688, 0.688, 0.696, \
0.688, 0.688, 0.688, 0.688, 0.688, 0.688, 0.688, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, \
0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.68, 0.672, 0.672, \
0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, \
0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.656, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.656, 0.664, 0.656, \
0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.648, 0.656, 0.656, 0.648, \
0.656, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.656, 0.656, 0.648, 0.648, \
0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.64, \
0.648, 0.648, 0.64, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, \
0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, \
0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.648, 0.656, \
0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, \
0.656, 0.656, 0.664, 0.656, 0.656, 0.656, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, 0.664, \
0.664, 0.672, 0.664, 0.664, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, 0.672, \
0.672, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.688, 0.68, 0.68, 0.688, 0.68, 0.688, \
0.688, 0.688, 0.688, 0.696, 0.696, 0.696, 0.696, 0.696, 0.696, 0.696, \
0.704, 0.704, 0.696, 0.704, 0.704, 0.704, 0.704, 0.704, 0.712, 0.712, \
0.712, 0.712, 0.712, 0.712, 0.72, 0.712, 0.72, 0.72, 0.728, 0.72, \
0.72, 0.728, 0.728, 0.728, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, \
0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.736, 0.744, 0.744, 0.744, 0.744, 0.752, 0.744, \
0.744, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.752, 0.76, \
0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, 0.76, \
0.768, 0.76, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, \
0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.768, 0.776, 0.768, \
0.768, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, \
0.776, 0.776, 0.784, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.776, 0.784, 0.776, 0.784, \
0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.792, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, \
0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.792, 0.784, 0.784, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.784, 0.792, 0.784, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.784, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.784, 0.784, 0.784, 0.792, 0.784, 0.792, \
0.784, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.784, 0.784, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.784, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.784, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.784, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.8, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.8, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.8, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.8, \
0.792, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, \
0.792, 0.8, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, \
0.792, 0.8, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792, 0.792}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say, you would be the best to detect such regions and select them manually but hey, thats not so much fun so lets try:

A straightforward (and sadly good way) is it to select the datapoints within a thereshold of the maximum. I've choosen 5% and got that:

```
thereshold=0.95;
maxData=thereshold*Max[data];
pData=DeleteCases[Table[If[maxData<data[[i]],{i,data[[i]]},Null],{i,1,Length[data]}],Null];
fit=LinearModelFit[pData,{1,x},x];
Show[ListPlot[data],Plot[fit["BestFit"],{x,0,2000},PlotStyle->Blue],ListPlot[pData,PlotStyle->Black]]
```

[image]

Another approach is a little more difficult. We smoothing out the data with a GaussianFilter. Then we select all points, where the neighborhood is only a special thereshold away in total difference to our startpoint. Sadly the result is a little bit more innacurate imo.

```
l=10;
smoothData=GaussianFilter[data,4l];
s=Flatten[DeleteCases[Reap[If[Total@Abs@Differences[smoothData[[#;;#+l]]]<0.0002,Sow[{#,smoothData[[#]]}]]&/@Range[1,Length[smoothData]-l]][[2]],Null],1];
fit=LinearModelFit[s,{1,x},x];
Show[ListPlot[data,ImageSize->Medium],Plot[fit["BestFit"],{x,0,2000},PlotStyle->Blue],ListPlot[s,PlotStyle->Black]]
```

[image]

Interesting task nevertheless. 
I'm sure someone better than me, will post a better code though.

Comment: Thank you Julien! I think Gaussian Filter will be very useful for me. Thank you for introducing me great code! :D

Answer (score 6):

You could try Quantile Regression.  The following regresses on the 90% quantile (other choices might be better), that is, it finds a line with 90% of the data below it.

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/QuantileRegression.m"]
fit = QuantileRegressionFit[Transpose[{Range[Length[data2]], data2}], {x, 1}, x, {0.9}]
(* {0.761387 + 0.0000220083 x} *)

ListPlot[{data2, Flatten[fit /. x -> Range[Length[data2]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your code! I think I can use this as well!